# Trying to test omniauth with rspec & Capybara, failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Using Rails 3.2 and the latest Rspec and Capybara, which means my Capybara specs live in `spec/features`.

I'm really new to Rails and testing, but I want to get used to testing. I ended up implementing OAuth before testing it. I finally got it working, and now I'm trying to retroactively test it (so I at least know if it breaks in the future). I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.zerosum.org/2011/03/19/easy-rails-outh-integration-testing.html), but things aren't working. Here's what I did:

1) Created `spec/support/integration_spec_helper.rb` with:

`module IntegrationSpecHelper
  def login_with_oauth(service = :google)
    visit "/auth/#{service}"
  end
end`

2) Modified `spec/spec_helper` to include `config.include IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :request` inside the `Rspec.configure` do block.

3) Created `spec/features/omniauth_spec.rb` with:

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature 'testing oauth' do
  scenario 'should create a new tiger' do
    login_with_oauth
    visit new_tiger_path

    fill_in 'tiger_name', :with => 'Charlie'
    fill_in 'tiger_blood', :with => 'yes'

    click_on 'Create Tiger'

    page.should have_content("Thanks! You are a winner!")
  end
end
```

Of course it's going to fail (I don't have tigers in my app) but I want it to fail on `visit new_tiger_path`. Instead, running the spec, I get:

`` 1) testing oauth should create a new tiger
     Failure/Error: login_with_oauth
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `login_with_oauth' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3:0x83355d8>
     # ./spec/features/omniauth_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' ``

So basically, it says there's no such thing `login_with_oauth`. This must be a really basic error, as my code isn't included for some reason.

I'm not using spork (trying to keep things simple).

Any idea what the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to use oauth from google, you'll want to change:

`def login_with_oauth(service = :google)`

**to:**

`def login_with_oauth(service = :google_oauth2)`

`:google_oauth2` should also be the first argument to **OmniAuth.config.add_mock**, i.e.:

```
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(
    :google_oauth2, 
    {
        :info => {
        :email => 'test@some_test_domain.com',
        :name=>'Test User'
    }
})
```

Don't forget to change:

`config.include(IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :request)`

**to:**

`config.include(IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :feature)` 
inside the RSpec.configure block, as Christoph noted above.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe I can help.
Got the same problem. It's caused by

```
config.include IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :request
```

The paramater ':type' needs to be changed to ':feature' because you write a rspec feature test.

Solution:

```
config.include IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :feature
```

Unfortunately this causes further problems, I couldn't solve yet.

Regards,
C-